# How do I find a time stamp on a file and then echo it into the contents of the file as the first line?

Tags: command-line, bash, sed

I have the following command that I'm trying to tweak:

```
stat -c %y test.txt | sed 's/^\([0-9\-]*\)/\1/'
```

This returns the following information:

```
2016-08-03 14:52:24.000000000
```

I need to tweak this so that it excludes the `.000000000` part of the output. I've tried a few different options but can't seem to get it right. Ultimately, I need to take the time stamp that I extract from the above command, and `echo` it as the first line into the file.

I have this command as an example that seems to correctly add a new line at the top of the file:

```
sed -i '1s/^/this should be a date\n/' test.txt
```

How do I combine the two commands?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
sed -i "1i$(stat -c %y test.txt | sed -r 's/\.[0-9]+ / /')" test.txt
```

Comment: Florian your example includes the trailing 00000 in the timestamp

Comment: @Happydevdays: I get something like `2016-08-03 17:41:42 +0200`. Maybe it's caused by the locales. Try `sed -r 's/\.[0-9]+//'`

Answer (score 5):

Like so:

```
( stat -c %y test_file.txt | awk -F '.' '{print $1}' ; cat test_file.txt  ) > /tmp/temp_file && mv /tmp/temp_file test_file.txt
```

Here's a small demo:

```
$> echo "Hello World" > test_file.txt
$> ( stat -c %y test_file.txt | awk -F '.' '{print $1}' ; cat test_file.txt  ) > /tmp/temp_file &&                       
> mv /tmp/temp_file test_file.txt
$> cat test_file.txt                                                                                                     
2016-08-03 09:24:27
Hello World
```

Explanation:

- We get timestamp and file contents in subshell , signified by parenthesis `(...)`
- `stat -c %y test_file.txt | awk -F '.' '{print $1}'` trimps timestamp
- `cat test_file.txt` reads file contents.
- The resulting text is timestamp plus whatever was in file, is being redirected to `/tmp/temp_file`
- Finally we replace original file with contents of `/tmp/temp_file`

Comment: Thanks so much for this helpful post.  I accepted the other answer only because it's a little more concise.

Answer (score 4):

How about using `ed` instead of `sed`?

```
$ ed -s test.txt << EOF
0r !stat -c \%y %
1 s/\.[0-9]*//
w
q
EOF
```

This says:

- read the output of command `stat -c \%y %` and insert it at position 0 in the buffer i.e. before the first line. Note that in `ed`, an *un*escaped `%` is shorthand for the current file.
- on this (now first) line, substitute nothing in place of the decimal period and following digits
- write the result back to the file and quit

The `-s` is optional - it just prevents `ed` from outputing line counts. If `stat` appends a timezone offset in your locale / timezone, and you wish to remove that as well, then you can modify the `s` command to remove the period and everything following it e.g. `s/\..*//`

It's also possible to use `ed` in a one-liner taking its commands from standard input using `echo` or `printf`, although it's a little tricky to get the escaping right:

```
printf '0r !stat -c \%%y %%\n1 s/\.[0-9]*//\nw\nq' | ed -s test.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

I realize this is an old post, but perhaps using Linux's "cut" command may make this solution a simple matter?

**Something like:**

```
stat -c %y 'composer.json' | cut -d '.' -f 1
```

THIS gave me a nice, clean output of:

```
2022-04-15 13:46:25
```

Instead of:

```
2022-04-15 13:46:25.692995716 -0600
```

I have found `cut` to be very useful for many similar jobs, and sometimes being much simpler than playing around with `awk`, `grep`, or `sed`, when a task requires something this simple.

Hope any future readers see this as a good solution for their needs.